# Load jQuery in node.js CLI

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm an R developer by day and I'm trying to learn to do stuff with Javascript at night.  I'm very used to the REPL type environment where I can run code in the IDE where I'm working.  The code I'm writing is for a web application, but I'm still in the learning stage with Javascript so I want to do exploration, practice, etc. and I'd like to do it in a REPL environment so I can try something, fail, try something else, etc.

I have installed node.js and configured Sublime Text to "build" my Javascript files via node in the CLI.  However, I'd like to try using some things from jQuery.  **Is there a way for me to load jQuery into the node.js execution environment so my standalone script can use the necessary features?**

To be clear, I'm not talking about use node.js on a server, as a webserver, any of that.  I'm just using node.js as an execution environment on my PC to execute vanilla and, hopefully, slightly french bean vanilla code.

I've read that you can't source in other Javascript files but obviously a web browser loads in code from multiple sources and co-mingles them so it seems like I should be able to do something similar when executing on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to try jQuery in a REPL environment, you can do that from the dev tool from your browser (major browsers has it called 'console' under F12 usually), no need for nodejs here, JS engines are implemented in browsers.

But if you want to use the same core functionality and syntax of jQuery, you might want to try cheerio package https://cheerio.js.org it's a:

> Fast, flexible, and lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server.